# Arc Length problem, not sure how to go about it.

Tags: calculus

if   $$4x^2 - y^2 = 64$$

show that:

$$ds^2 = \frac4{y^2}(5x^2 - 16)dx^2$$

I'm not sure what to do. Could someone explain it to me?  I tried solving for y and then plugging it into the Arc Length formula to see if anything clicked, but nothing looked right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  The basic intuition behind the arc length formula is that a small arc of any (well-behaved) curve is approximately straight, so an infinitely small arc of a curve can be considered exactly straight.  So by the Pythagorean theorem, $dx^2 + dy^2 = ds^2$.  Now just use $d(4x^2-y^2) = d(64)$ to write $dy$ in terms of $dx$.

Comment: So $d(4x^2-y^2)$ is the same as $d(4x^2)/d(y^2)$? I already marked your the correct answer but just want to make sure.

Comment: No, $d(4x^2 - y) = d(4x^2) - d(y^2)$.

Comment: Manipulating differentials is very similar to manipulating derivatives.  So for instance, just as $\frac{d}{dx}(f+g) = \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{dg}{dx}$, we have $d(f+g) = df + dg$.  Usually you can just take a relationship involving $\frac{d}{dx}$ and then multiply both sides by $dx$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

You have: $$ds^2 = dy^2 + dx^2 \\= ((4x/y)dx)^2 + (dx)^2 \\= (16x^2 +y^2)/y^2*(dx)^2 \\= (16x^2 + 4x^2 -64)/y^2*(dx)^2\\ = 4/y^2*(5x^2 - 16)*(dx)^2$$.

Comment: How did you get $((4x/y)dx)^2$?

Comment: You take d both sides and get: 2ydy = 8xdx and solve for dy.